# Why is necessary non-linear model?

Tags: linear-model, nonlinear

I think **linear model** is such as linear regression, logistic regression (including one with polynomial features), SVM (including one with kernel).

I think **non-linear model** is such as decision tree, random forest, neural network, kNN.

Why do we need non-linear model, though we can deal with **non-linear separable** problem, using linear model (logistic regression, SVM etc, with **polynomial feature** or **kernel** trick)?

**Polynomial feature** strategy is computationally less effective than non-linear model? Is it also likely to cause **the curse of dimension**? That is, is polynomial feature strategy more likely to cause over-fitting than non-linear models?

Comment: Why use screwdriver if you have a hammer?

Comment: @Tim's comment is fun, but of course we need some explanation how the screwdriver is better suited for certain problems than a hammer. The polynomial feature strategy being less effective than the use of nonlinear models is one such argument.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing dimensionality with **polynomial features** will hurt performance, or even make storing  data infeasible if you start with too high dimension.

Kernel trick is strictly more powerful than adding finitely many features: for example using rbf kernel enables you to perform implicitly learning in an infinite-dimensional space.